# Why In App Purchase goes to SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed?

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have implimented In App Purchase in my application. when i try to buy a product it goes to `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` and gives the error message `Can't connect to the iTunes Store` when i press a button to buy product then this code is called

```
  MKStoreManager * manager = [MKStoreManager sharedManager];
            
[manager buyFeatureA];
```

the classes that i am using for purchase are given on these links

[MKStoreManager](http://qasimshah.sitesled.com/In%20APP%20Purchase/MKStoreManager.zip)

[MKStoreObserver](http://qasimshah.sitesled.com/In%20APP%20Purchase/MKStoreObserver.zip)

Please help me i am so much worried about this :(

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys in my case i didn't uploaded the application on App store. For In App Purchase we should upload our app on app store and when app is in "Waiting for review" state then reject your App Binary and then check In App Purchase in your App.

Comment: and please check in itunes "Tax and Banking" and also setup your tax and banking for iOS Paid applications

Comment: http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/invalid-product-ids/comment-page-2/#comment-7996 that was very useful for me

Comment: Do we need to do it ? as when i checked in iOS developer Library it was given that "its not needed to upload the build in app store for testing ".

Comment: Though they have written this but i always have to upload for testing

Comment: do u have any sample for in app purchase. i have been trying from long but I'm always getting this Failed error.

Comment: if you upload , then you need to upload using distribution account but for testing we need development profile ? am i right ?

Comment: @ishhhh MKStoreManger updated classes are available on github so please check them out

Comment: No need to upload the actual app

Answer (score 1):

Check carefully the product id that you are requesting to itunes Connect should be the same that is created in itunes for purchases.

Comment: Sometimes the sandbox site is down. Is it happening consistently?

Comment: I just copied the identifier from Itunes and them pasted in my code but it is happening consistently. and i am messing with this problem from 1 week :(